# Why is my AJAX method sending form input to the URL?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Once a user submits their form, I want to use JQuery/AJAX to stop the page from redirecting/reloading.

But what is happening, is the user data is refreshed and displayed in the URL - even though I am using the POST method!

I have 2 forms on my landing.html page, but I'll just give the coding for 1 of them:

It seems my problem is here somewhere in my contactForm.js:

```
        $(function() {

      $("#contactUsForm input,#contactUsForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
          // additional error messages or events
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
          // get values from FORM
          var name = $("input#c_fName").val();
          var email = $("input#c_email").val();
          var phone = $("input#c_phone").val();
          var message = $("textarea#c_message").val();
          var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
          // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
          if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
          }
          
          $.ajax({
            url: "././forms/contactUsForm.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              name: name,
              phone: phone,
              email: email,
              message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
              // Success message
              $('#c_success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactUsForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
              // Fail message
              $('#c_success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactUsForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
              }, 1000);
            }
          });
        },
        filter: function() {
          return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
      });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
      });
    });

    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#c_fName').focus(function() {
      $('#c_success').html('');
    });
```

landing.html : contactUsForm:

```
<form name="contactUsForm" id="contactUsForm" action="forms/contactUsForm.php" method="POST">
           
          <!--    First Name      -->
          <div class="control-group form-group col-12" >
            <div class="controls">
              <label for="c_fName">Full Name:</label>
              <input 
              type="text" 
              class="form-control" 
              id="c_fName" 
              name="c_fName" 
              required 
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter your full name.."
              placeholder="Johnny Smith">
            </div>
            
          </div>
          
          <!--   Phone Number      -->
          <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <label for="c_phone">Phone Number:</label>
              <input 
              type="tel" 
              class="form-control" 
              id="c_phone" 
              name="c_phone" 
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number." 
              placeholder="Example: 021 XXX XXXX...">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!--    Email Address      -->
          <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <label for="c_email">Email Address:</label>
              <input 
              type="email" 
              class="form-control" 
              id="c_email" 
              name="c_email" 
              required 
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address." 
              placeholder="Example: jane.doe@email.com">
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!--    Message      -->
          <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <label for="c_message">Message:</label>
              <textarea 
              rows="6" 
              cols="100" 
              class="form-control" 
              id="c_message" 
              name="c_message" 
              required 
              data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" 
              maxlength="999" s
              tyle="resize:none" 
              placeholder="Please tell us about your enquiry...">
              </textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="c_success"></div>
          
          
          <button 
          type="submit" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          id="sendMessageButton" 
          style="width: 100%;margin: auto" >
          Send Message</button>
          
          
        </form>
```

My contactUsForm.php is working correctly if I do **not** use AJAX:

```
        <?php 
    $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['c_fName']));
    $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['c_email']));
    $phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['c_phone']));
    $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['c_message']));
       
    // Create the email and send the message
    $to = 'email@email.com'; 
    $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
    $headers = "From: email@email.com\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    return true;         
    ?>
```

If I do not use the AJAX function, the form is submitted, the email sent off and page redirected (Which i do not want)

I have written these forms over and over to try fix this. And every other form I've made works perfect with AJAX. These files are located at the end the file:

```
<script src="assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>         
<script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.min.js" ></script><!--Used for other form-->
<script src="js/bookingForm.js"></script>
<script src="js/contactForm.js"></script>
```

---

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like the regular form submission is happening instead of the AJAX call. Can you verify in your Network tab of the Developer toolbar if this is true?

Comment: @El_Vanja I just had a look, and that is exactly what is happening. Its not running the AJAX code at all. I've also tried calling the code as a `onsubmit()` function on the button itself - but with no luck.

Comment: I've never used `jqBootstrapValidation` so I don't know the mechanics. Have you tried logging something from inside it to see if any of its handlers are triggered (`submitError` and `submitSuccess`)?

Comment: Running the code locally I get an error in your $.ajax `complete` callback of `$this is undefined`. It works with `$(this)` instead. Do you get any other console errors when running the script yourself?

Comment: @El_Vanja You were correct, I used the `console.log` at the beginning of each function to get the results. I have updated my code now with the working code and my console log

Comment: @Matt You are a star! I was also getting this error in my log, and applied your suggestion and its working perfectly!!! I will post my log and working code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to @Matt & @El_Vanja for helping with this. I know its not correct for me to post the answer myself. But thought it will help any future devs experiencing the same problem.

## After @El_Vanja's suggestion

I added `console.log` to each function running to find the problem. The code was running and the email was being sent, but the form data was not binding to the email. This was because the incorrect variable names were used.

## After @Matt's suggestion

The code was running, the email was being sent with the form data, but I was still getting  `$this is undefined` in my `console.log` on the `$.ajax complete` function. I then followed @Matt's suggestion and change `$this` to `$(this)`. After updating the code, its working:

### CONSOLE LOG

```
submitSuccess has started          contactUsForm.js:11:13
variables have been assigned       contactUsForm.js:20:14
Variable assignment complete       contactUsForm.js:24:14
AJAX Success is starting           contactUsForm.js:36:14
```

### UPDATED contactUsForm.js

```
        $(function() {

      $("#contactUsForm input,#contactUsForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
          // additional error messages or events
          console.log('Error occured between line 5 - 8');
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            
            console.log('submitSuccess has started');
          event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
          // get values from FORM
          var c_fName = $("input#c_fName").val();
          var c_email = $("input#c_email").val();
          var c_phone = $("input#c_phone").val();
          var c_message = $("textarea#c_message").val();
          var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
          // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
          console.log('variables have been assigned');
          if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = c_fName.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
          }
          console.log('Variable assignment complete');
          $.ajax({
            url: "././forms/contactUsForm.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
              c_fName: c_fName,
              c_phone: c_phone,
              c_email: c_email,
              c_message: c_message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                console.log('AJAX Success is starting');
              // Success message
              $('#c_success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-success')
                .append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactUsForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
              // Fail message
              console.log('AJAX error is occuring');
              $('#c_success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                .append("</button>");
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').append($("<strong>").text("Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!"));
              $('#c_success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
              //clear all fields
              $('#contactUsForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            complete: function() {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
              }, 1000);
            }
          });
        },
        filter: function() {
          return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
      });

      $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
      });
    });

    /*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
    $('#c_fName').focus(function() {
      $('#c_success').html('');
    });
```

No change was needed in the contactUsForm.php file